# How to access an arraylist from another class

Tags: java, object, arraylist, text-files

So I have three separate classes named: 1. User Interface; this is where the user can input data via methods from the second class 2. Directory; this is where I load a text file into an arraylist, and there are a bunch of methods in this class. 3. Person class; this is the object with constructors first/last name, initials and phone number. I finished coding my Directory and Person class and now I need to code the User Interface class, how would I access the arraylist from the Directory class so I could use my methods? So far my User Interface class is like this:

```
public class UserInterface
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        Directory directory = new Directory();

        showMenu();
        char userInput = kbd.next().charAt(0);

        directory.getArrayList();

        if (userInput == 'p' || userInput == 'P'){
            directory.optionP();
        }
        else if (userInput == 'l' || userInput == 'L'){
            directory.optionL();
        }
        else if (userInput == 'r' || userInput == 'R'){
            directory.optionR();
        }
        else if (userInput == 'c' || userInput == 'C'){
            directory.optionC();
        }
        else if (userInput == 'a' || userInput == 'A'){
            directory.optionA();
        }
        else if (userInput == 'd' || userInput == 'D'){
            directory.optionD();
        }
        else {
            directory.optionE();
        }


        System.out.println ("Thank you for using the Directory System");
    }
}
```

And my Directory class:

```
public class Directory{

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
    ArrayList <Person> persons = new ArrayList <Person>();

    public void run() throws FileNotFoundException{
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String initial;
        String department;
        int telNum;

        File inFile = new File ("phone.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner (inFile);

        while (in.hasNext()){
            Person list;
            lastName = in.next();
            firstName = in.next();
            initial = in.next();
            department = in.next();
            telNum = in.nextInt();
            list = new Person(lastName, firstName, initial, department, telNum);
            persons.add(list);
        }
        in.close();


        System.out.println(persons);
    }
}
```

Get ArrayList Method: `public void getArrayList(){
        System.out.println(persons);
    }`

When I run my User Interface Class and select an option, the arraylist is blank, so what should I do in this class in order to access the arraylist from the Directory class?

Answer (score 0):

The method `run()` does not seem to getting called anywhere. It could be the case that you have left the piece of code that invokes this method out but from the way that the problem has been presented, that seems unlikely.

I recommend:

1. Changing the name of `run()` to `init()` or `initialize()`. The main reason for doing this is that `run()` usually associated with `Runnable`.
2. Explicitly calling the `init()` or `initialize()` function to ensure that it is being called.
3. Call the `toLowerCase` method on the `char` so that you simplify your conditional logic: [toLowerCase(char) method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447580/tolowercasechar-method)
4. Also, I highly recommend changing the name of the `Person` variable to `person` rather than `list`. This might cause confusion later on because a `Person` is not a `List`.

Lastly, from the comments, I dont quite understand what you mean by 'it is still blank'. How is this determination made? Could you please provide code that?

Answer (score -2):

You need to put your `arrayList` as a public attribute, then you need to create an object of the  Directory class. This instance will let you control all the attributes of the `arrayList`.

To access an attribute use " . " after the object name.

Put your attribute as private, set a `getArrayList` method that returns your attribute.

Then create a new Directory object.

Call your method using `dirObj.getArrayList`

Comment: Could you show me, I kinda get what you're saying but not sure how to write it out

Comment: in your Directory class change this 
ArrayList <Person> persons = new ArrayList <Person>();

 with public ArrayList <Person> persons = new ArrayList <Person>();
then , go to your UserInterface class and create an object of your directoryclass

Directory dirObj = new Directory();

this will allow you to to access your attributes like this 
(dirObj.persons ) will give you the value of your arrayList

Comment: Why are you recommending use of public fields?? You know that you're breaking encapsulation in this way and propagating bad habits.

Comment: And @DeemAh please don't ask for someone to write code for you. Take the idea and first try to write it yourself, then if stuck, show what you've tried.

Comment: he seems like a beginner , and i gave him the easiest way

Comment: @AhmedBaoun yeah i can't break encapsulation >.> any other method?

Comment: @AhmedBaoun ok I added a "directory.getArraylist()" in user interface class and a getArrayList method in my directory class, but its still blank. (I updated my code)

Comment: a getter method is a method that returns the value , and doesn't only display it ,you should work on that

Comment: @AhmedBaoun so is it "public String getArrayList(){ 'while loop code'?

Comment: @DeemAh it's public ArrayList getArrayList(){return persons;}